# d3 enter() update() exit() not updating a chart

Tags: d3.js

I am able to update my chart by selecting and updating individual attributes but not through enter, update, exit.

This code seems to work just fine:

```
        var chart = d3.select(svg).select("svg");

        chart.selectAll("rect").data(data)
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { 
                return i*bar_width; 
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) { 
                return height - Math.abs(y(d) / 2) - height / 2 + 2;
             })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                 return Math.abs(y(d));
            })
            .attr("width", bar_width);
```

However, the below code (where I use enter, update, exit) does not work:

```
        var chart = d3.select(svg).select("svg");

        chart.selectAll("rect").data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")                 //Enter
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {             //Update
                return i*bar_width; 
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) { 
                return height - Math.abs(y(d) / 2) - height / 2 + 2;
             })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                 return Math.abs(y(d));
            })
            .attr("width", bar_width);                  

        chart.selectAll("rect").exit().remove();     //Remove
```

I wonder why? FYI: I am using d3 v5.

Comment: The first code only works because you already have elements in that SVG, since it doesn't append anything. Anyway, is your question why don't the second code works? If *"yes"* that's certainly a duplicate (by the way, that pattern is incorrect).

Comment: Yes, my intention was for the second code to be a duplicate of the first one (but the second code is not working). What would the correct pattern look like? I am testing enter, update, exit pattern because I need it for some follow up work.

Comment: The second one is not a duplicate of the first because the first one doesn't append anything! Also, in your second code, you have only an **enter** selection. Have a look at the correct pattern: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218